# Total Score of TopTags in AndroidApp does not match

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page, android-app

I have noticed that the score of Top Tags in the Android App does not match the score on my profile.

As an example does my Profile say that I have a score of 806 in the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), while the Android App displays a score of 881. The score of all Top Tags do not match.